# Validation rule to prevent all other users from changing lead status when lead is "New"

Tags: validation, validation-rule, status

I am trying to create a validation rule to prevent users that aren't associated with the user Id profiles from changing a "New" Lead Status to any other status

When I check the syntax for the below, it says The there is a ')' missing somewhere

```
AND(  
    ISCHANGED(Status), 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"New"), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Working"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "MQL"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Unqualified"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Sales Qualified"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Decision Maker"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Won"),
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Lost"),
    $User.ProfileId <>"0e2M000001yVtl",
    $User.ProfileId <>"00e41000001XST2",

)
```

Comment: Do not use hard-coded Ids. Much better to filter on `$User.Profile.Name`.

Comment: Or on `$Permission`.

Comment: Checking what the value changes to is a bit redundant unless you only want to prevent changes to certain values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma at the end.

Also, you're going to need to mix AND and OR; this rule cannot currently fire.

```
AND(  
    ISCHANGED(Status), 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"New"), 
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Working"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "MQL"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Unqualified"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Sales Qualified"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Decision Maker"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Won"),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Lost")
    ),
    $User.ProfileId <>"0e2M000001yVtl",
    $User.ProfileId <>"00e41000001XST2"
)
```

---

From a practical standpoint, you can also simply say:

```
AND(  
    ISCHANGED(Status), 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"New"), 
    $User.ProfileId <>"0e2M000001yVtl",
    $User.ProfileId <>"00e41000001XST2"
)
```

This fits the semantics better; if it changes from New to ANY other value, even values you don't have yet, this rule will prevent the edit.

---

Finally, consider using profile names, instead:

```
AND(  
    ISCHANGED(Status), 
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"New"), 
    $User.Profile.Name <> "Name 1",
    $User.Profile.Name <>"Name 2"
)
```